# Insert_textbox in a worksheet in the same workbook as a chartsheet

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Using Python 3.5 and xlsxwriter 0.9.6.

I'm having a problem inserting a textbox in a worksheet, when there is also a chartsheet in the same workbook.

Below I've used an example from the xlsxwriter documentation (http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_data_table.html) and added in a textbox to the worksheet portion.

```
# Copyright 2013-2016, John McNamara, jmcnamara@cpan.org
#
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chartsheet.xlsx')

# Add a worksheet to hold the data.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a chartsheet. A worksheet that only holds a chart.
chartsheet = workbook.add_chartsheet()

# Add a format for the headings.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2']
data = [
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
[30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

#Section I've added in
tb_options = {
'width': 10,
'height': 10,
'x_offset': 5,
'y_offset': 5,
'fill': {'color': 'gray'}}
worksheet.insert_textbox('A15', " ", tb_options)
#End of Section I've added in

# Create a new bar chart.
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'bar'})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
'name':       '=Sheet1!$B$1',
'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

# Configure a second series. Use of alternative syntax define ranges.
chart1.add_series({
'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, 2],
'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 6, 0],
'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 2, 6, 2],
})

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart1.set_title ({'name': 'Results of sample analysis'})
chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Test number'})
chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Sample length (mm)'})

# Set an Excel chart style.
chart1.set_style(11)

# Add the chart to the chartsheet.
chartsheet.set_chart(chart1)

workbook.close()
```

The error generated by excel says:
"We found a problem with some content in 'chartsheet.xlsx'.Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, Click Yes."

I'd like to avoid having this error if possible. If I omit the chartsheet from the code and just the worksheet is produced then the text_box is added without problems.

Does anybody know of a solution, where you can have a worksheet with a textbox inside in addition to a chartsheet in the same workbook?

Comment: That looks like a bug. You should open an Issue with the above sample code on the [XlsxWriter tracker](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara. I've opened an issue on GitHub.